# Yii2 could not convert local time to GMT timezone

Tags: php, yii2

I am new to yii2, my question is when I trying to convert local to GMT it can not be converted into GMT, I don't know the issue.

```
$time = gmdate('H:i', strtotime('17:20'));
```

its returns 17:20. 
expected output -: 11:50 (converted into GMT). Is any issue in yii2 or any config setting. because above code works good in core php.

Comment: What're your expecting output?

Comment: You set the format with `H:i`, and the output is in that format, what's issue here?

Comment: I want to convert this string 17:20 to GMT time zone that is 11:50. its work good in core php but having some issue in yii2.

Comment: use `strtotime('17:20 T')` to include timezone when converting to unixtime

Comment: Dear, Muhammad this solution not work it returns 00:20

Comment: Make sure you have correct timezone set in app config's `timeZone`. https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-base-application#$timeZone-detail

Comment: also check if you are setting default timezone in the config file for `Yii2` you can do so by adding `'timeZone' => 'America/Los_Angeles', `

Comment: I checked with all above solutions when I set timezone "America/Los_Angeles"  in config file its work. but I want to convert my time to UTC timezone it could not work. My question is any issue UTC timezone in Yii2?

Comment: @Pranit you need to set the timezone to your timezone instead of `America/Los_Angeles`

Answer (score 3):

I found the answer, the default timezone of yii2 is in UTC because of this I cant convert UTC to UTC.
For this I get local timezone using jquery (without affecting yii2 and server default settings), and convert the time using local timezone to UTC.

```
$date = new \DateTime($postData['ArrivalTime'], new \DateTimeZone('Asia/Kolkata'));
 $date->format('H:i');
 $date->setTimezone(new \DateTimeZone('UTC'));
 $Time = $date->format('H:i'); //11:50:00
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to convert from one time zone to another regardless of server settings and Yii2 settings, use DateTime and do that

```
$localTime = '17:20';
$dt = date_create($localTime, new DateTimeZone('Asia/Kolkata'))
  ->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone('UTC'))
;
echo $dt->format("H:i:s"); //11:50:00
```

However, if Asia/Kolkata is your correct local time zone you would like to work with within Yii2, then set it in the configuration as well.